# Call angular scope function in index.html via href

Tags: html, angularjs, yeoman

I have user controller with logout function inside. Now I want to call logout function via href in index.html. Btw I'm using yeoman. The href is located at the navigation bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do. In my app I have an auth module with a controller attached to a route '#/logout', that controller handles the log out functionality via an auth service. So, in the link you'd have something like this:

```
<a href="#/logout">Log out</a>
```

When logged out app simply redirect user to #/